# Internal battery recommendation for a Goal Zero 1000

Tags: 12v

I have a Goal Zero 1000 and the internal battery is dead. I tried with customer service and with the page but they don't have any option and don't have a battery to buy as a replacement. The internal battery is 10.8V and all the battery out there are 12V. The question is if there is an option to use the 12v battery safely if it fits the internal box of the goal zero.

This is the goal zero:

https://www.goalzero.com/shop/power-stations/goal-zero-yeti-1000-lithium-portable-power-station/

Is a box with a lithium battery, an inverter and some ports for 12V usage and 5V USB charging.

Inside use a 10.8V 96.8Ah battery (1045 Watts Hour) , this battery is a lot of small cells wrapped all together and chained.

This is like a power generator, it can be charged with solar panels and with the wall.

Comment: What is a Goal Zero 1000 and is it related to a Binford 3000?

Comment: Please post as much detailed information from the dead battery as you can - any tags or stickers, pictures, its dimensions..

Comment: what did customer service say to you?

Comment: Sorry I added some additional information

Comment: Customer Service response:

Soft Reset

1. Press and Hold the units button for about 15-30 seconds.

2. You will see the screen go blank and come back. This means the unit has been reset.

3. Try charging unit for 6 hours.

 

Hard Reset

1. Press and Hold the units and Info button simultaneously for about 15-30 seconds.

2. You will see the screen go blank and come back. This means the unit has been reset.

3. Try recharging unit for 6 hours.

Comment: Why the question was close I was not asking for a product just how to convert if possible the voltage what a bunch of idiots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manufacturer website, it looks like they are using a 10.8V LiNiMnCo chemistry battery pack. The charging voltage is 11.1, and the unit won't work with a 12V battery.